# Issue downloading/parsing ORC File from S3, or from Local Path

Tags: java, amazon-s3, filereader, orc

I have an application deployed that is supposed to parse/download an ORC File from an S3 bucket.

I have tried multiple things, one of them being, downloading the File locally in the app, and try to create an OrcReader object using the `createReader` method form Hadoop, using the Hadoop.fs.Path, passing in as an argument the path to the app local file. But every time I'm getting:

```
- Unknown error occurred
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not found
```

My code is:

```
final GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                                                           .bucket(s3Bucket)
                                                           .key(fullPath)
                                                           .build();
    try (final ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> responseInputStream = s3Client.getObject(objectRequest);
        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadPath)) {

      IOUtils.copyLarge(responseInputStream, fileOutputStream);

      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
      conf.set("fs.https.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
      conf.set("fs.https.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpsFileSystem.class.getName());

      return createReader(new Path(downloadPath.toString()), readerOptions(conf));
```

But I am still getting the error.
This would've been way easier with a CSV, and using BufferedReader but unfortunately that is not the case.
Also I don't want to read every line from S3 and copy the contents of the file to a temporary file as this will affect the performance of the application

I do have the orc dependency in my pom, as well as the hadoop-common one.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it has very little to do with what your code does, but rather how it's packaged and run. You are missing hadoop classes in classpath - how do you run the code?

Comment: A scheduled cronjob runs the above code. What other Hadoop libraries do you suggest I should have?